# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment. EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, maven, activemq-classic, testng, fatal-error

I have java 1.6, maven 2, activeMQ 5.5 and functional tests with testng. When I launch it in Idea then OK, but when I try to launch them with maven from console then process suspends after trying to send message via activeMQ and after some time crashes with the following error in log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d92f7a6, pid=5716, tid=7000
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x9f7a6]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000072b6000):  JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616" [_thread_in_vm, id=7000, stack(0x000000000d630000,0x000000000d730000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000000bb02d5c

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000bae2a70, RBX=0x00000000bd6a85f2, RCX=0x0000000000008000, RDX=0x00000000000080bb
RSP=0x000000000d72f250, RBP=0x0000000000000002, RSI=0x0000000000000003, RDI=0x00000000000000a5
R8 =0x000000000bae2e00, R9 =0x000000006d890000, R10=0x000000000d72f430, R11=0x000000000000000c
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000bd6a8600, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000000006
RIP=0x000000006d92f7a6, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000d72f250)
0x000000000d72f250:   0000000000000000 000000006d95294d
0x000000000d72f260:   000000000baf3800 000000006daea964
0x000000000d72f270:   00000000004ebb80 00000000072b6000
0x000000000d72f280:   0000000000000000 000000006d92f49c
0x000000000d72f290:   00000000bd6a85f0 000000006da7bc86
0x000000000d72f2a0:   0000000000000010 000000000bae2a70
0x000000000d72f2b0:   0000000000000000 00000000072b6000
0x000000000d72f2c0:   000000000d72f430 0000000000000020
0x000000000d72f2d0:   0000000000000014 000000006d92fec2
0x000000000d72f2e0:   000000000d72f430 0000000008cf3200
0x000000000d72f2f0:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x000000000d72f300:   0000000000000001 00000000072b6000
0x000000000d72f310:   00000000072b6000 000000006d95294d
0x000000000d72f320:   000000000d72f398 00000000004e9920
0x000000000d72f330:   0000000000000000 000007fefdf7132c
0x000000000d72f340:   0000000000000000 000000006d9a7a6f 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006d92f7a6)
0x000000006d92f786:   0f b7 44 1c 01 0f b6 c8 66 89 44 24 20 0f b6 44
0x000000006d92f796:   24 21 66 c1 e1 08 0f b7 d1 48 0b d0 49 8b 42 20
0x000000006d92f7a6:   0f b7 0c 90 66 41 89 4c 1c 01 e9 2a 01 00 00 45
0x000000006d92f7b6:   8d 46 01 48 8b d3 49 8b ca e8 8c f9 ff ff 44 8a 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000bae2a70 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000bd6a85f2 is an oop
{constMethod} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - method:       0x00000000bd6a8600 {method} '<init>' '(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in 'java/io/EOFException'
 - exceptions:   0x00000000bae01ef8
bci_from(00000000BD6A85F2) = 2; print_codes():
RCX=0x0000000000008000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000000080bb is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000d72f250 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000072b6000
RBP=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000000000a5 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000bae2e00 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000006d890000 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000000d72f430 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000072b6000
R11=0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000bd6a8600 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000000d630000,0x000000000d730000],  sp=0x000000000d72f250,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x9f7a6]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.io.DataInputStream.readInt()I+44
j  org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(Ljava/io/DataInput;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand()Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun()V+1
j  org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run()V+47
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000a457800 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@88821c2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5024, stack(0x0000000011100000,0x0000000011200000)]
  0x000000000a456800 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@32417348" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5852, stack(0x0000000010e00000,0x0000000010f00000)]
  0x000000000a456000 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@5ea39955" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6460, stack(0x0000000010d00000,0x0000000010e00000)]
  0x000000000a452800 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@35c71452" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7196, stack(0x0000000010900000,0x0000000010a00000)]
  0x000000000a453000 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@14b28d06" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7096, stack(0x000000000b150000,0x000000000b250000)]
  0x000000000a454800 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@393a037e" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1760, stack(0x0000000009ce0000,0x0000000009de0000)]
  0x000000000a453800 JavaThread "DefaultMessageListenerContainer-9" [_thread_blocked, id=1172, stack(0x0000000010c00000,0x0000000010d00000)]
  0x000000000a455000 JavaThread "Ta" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6248, stack(0x0000000011f00000,0x0000000012000000)]
  0x000000000767c000 JavaThread "Camel (clientProcessorHubCamelContext) thread #6 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Tests.ProcessorHub" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4996, stack(0x000000000da30000,0x000000000db30000)]
  0x000000000c056800 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1032, stack(0x0000000011a00000,0x0000000011b00000)]
  0x000000000c055800 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-2 - Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18889" [_thread_blocked, id=6444, stack(0x0000000011900000,0x0000000011a00000)]
  0x000000000c055000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18889" [_thread_in_native, id=6676, stack(0x0000000011800000,0x0000000011900000)]
  0x000000000c054800 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6976, stack(0x0000000011700000,0x0000000011800000)]
  0x000000000c053800 JavaThread "Camel (processorHubCamelContext) thread #5 - seda://phub" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3480, stack(0x0000000011600000,0x0000000011700000)]
  0x000000000c051800 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616" [_thread_blocked, id=6868, stack(0x0000000011300000,0x0000000011400000)]
  0x000000000c050800 JavaThread "Camel (processorHubCamelContext) thread #4 - JmsConsumer[Tests.ProcessorHub" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6884, stack(0x0000000011200000,0x0000000011300000)]
  0x000000000c04f000 JavaThread "Camel (processorHubCamelContext) thread #3 - ThroughputLogger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6600, stack(0x0000000011000000,0x0000000011100000)]
  0x000000000c03e000 JavaThread "Camel (processorHubCamelContext) thread #2 - ThroughputLogger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7364, stack(0x0000000010f00000,0x0000000011000000)]
  0x000000000c03d000 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-2 - Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18882" [_thread_in_native, id=2168, stack(0x0000000010b00000,0x0000000010c00000)]
  0x000000000c03c800 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18882" [_thread_in_native, id=4976, stack(0x0000000010a00000,0x0000000010b00000)]
  0x000000000c03b000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.Order.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4132, stack(0x0000000010800000,0x0000000010900000)]
  0x000000000c03a800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.AdjustmentLog.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5136, stack(0x0000000010700000,0x0000000010800000)]
  0x000000000c039800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.HoldLog.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6696, stack(0x0000000010600000,0x0000000010700000)]
  0x000000000c039000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.Account.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6968, stack(0x0000000010500000,0x0000000010600000)]
  0x000000000c038000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.JournalEntry.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6916, stack(0x0000000010400000,0x0000000010500000)]
  0x000000000c037800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.User.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7360, stack(0x0000000010300000,0x0000000010400000)]
  0x000000000c036800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.TransactionRecord.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5396, stack(0x0000000010200000,0x0000000010300000)]
  0x000000000a41c800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.Address.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7684, stack(0x0000000010100000,0x0000000010200000)]
  0x000000000a41c000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.Base.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6660, stack(0x0000000010000000,0x0000000010100000)]
  0x000000000a41b000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.Card.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1300, stack(0x000000000ff00000,0x0000000010000000)]
  0x000000000a41a800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.txvia.domain.LedgerAccount.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6944, stack(0x000000000fe00000,0x000000000ff00000)]
  0x000000000a41a000 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@306715f8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7540, stack(0x000000000fd00000,0x000000000fe00000)]
  0x000000000a419000 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8148, stack(0x000000000fc00000,0x000000000fd00000)]
  0x000000000a418800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2 - Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18881" [_thread_blocked, id=4804, stack(0x000000000fb00000,0x000000000fc00000)]
  0x000000000a417800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18881" [_thread_in_native, id=7632, stack(0x000000000fa00000,0x000000000fb00000)]
  0x000000000a417000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCurrency.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5260, stack(0x000000000e930000,0x000000000ea30000)]
  0x000000000a416000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTProgram.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6792, stack(0x000000000e830000,0x000000000e930000)]
  0x000000000a415800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTAccount.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7996, stack(0x000000000e730000,0x000000000e830000)]
  0x000000000767b800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCard.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4296, stack(0x000000000e630000,0x000000000e730000)]
  0x0000000007468000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTCardHolder.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5372, stack(0x000000000e530000,0x000000000e630000)]
  0x0000000007467000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.idt.domain.IDTTransaction.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5412, stack(0x000000000e430000,0x000000000e530000)]
  0x0000000007466800 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@5c4ef185" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2372, stack(0x000000000d930000,0x000000000da30000)]
  0x00000000072b7800 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7528, stack(0x000000000d830000,0x000000000d930000)]
  0x00000000072b0800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-2 - Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18880" [_thread_blocked, id=2220, stack(0x000000000d330000,0x000000000d430000)]
  0x00000000072b4000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18880" [_thread_in_native, id=1144, stack(0x0000000009ae0000,0x0000000009be0000)]
  0x0000000007465000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiCurrency.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6440, stack(0x000000000e330000,0x000000000e430000)]
  0x0000000007464000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiTransaction.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6896, stack(0x000000000e230000,0x000000000e330000)]
  0x0000000007463800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiCustomer.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7784, stack(0x000000000e130000,0x000000000e230000)]
  0x0000000007462800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiAccount.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7280, stack(0x000000000e030000,0x000000000e130000)]
  0x0000000007462000 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiProduct.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6612, stack(0x000000000df30000,0x000000000e030000)]
  0x0000000007461800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiUserCertificate.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6096, stack(0x000000000de30000,0x000000000df30000)]
  0x0000000007460800 JavaThread "com.nxsystems.simulator.denarii.domain.DenariiCard.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4156, stack(0x000000000dd30000,0x000000000de30000)]
  0x000000000767e800 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@7fec0e19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7448, stack(0x000000000dc30000,0x000000000dd30000)]
  0x000000000767d000 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4012, stack(0x000000000db30000,0x000000000dc30000)]
  0x00000000072b7000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Scheduler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7736, stack(0x000000000d730000,0x000000000d830000)]
=>0x00000000072b6000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616" [_thread_in_vm, id=7000, stack(0x000000000d630000,0x000000000d730000)]
  0x00000000072b5800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7464, stack(0x000000000d530000,0x000000000d630000)]
  0x00000000072b4800 JavaThread "Camel (camelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[Tests.Events]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5552, stack(0x000000000d430000,0x000000000d530000)]
  0x00000000072b3000 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor WriteCheck" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5192, stack(0x000000000b250000,0x000000000b350000)]
  0x00000000072b1800 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616" [_thread_blocked, id=5416, stack(0x0000000009fa0000,0x000000000a0a0000)]
  0x00000000072b1000 JavaThread "Camel (camelContext) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[Tests.DebitCard]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5348, stack(0x0000000009be0000,0x0000000009ce0000)]
  0x0000000005f7e000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=984, stack(0x0000000006520000,0x0000000006620000)]
  0x0000000005f71000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5940, stack(0x0000000006420000,0x0000000006520000)]
  0x00000000005e8800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7816, stack(0x0000000006320000,0x0000000006420000)]
  0x00000000005e6800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7060, stack(0x0000000006220000,0x0000000006320000)]
  0x00000000005e6000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6732, stack(0x0000000006120000,0x0000000006220000)]
  0x00000000005d1000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2908, stack(0x0000000005e20000,0x0000000005f20000)]
  0x00000000005c8000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4736, stack(0x0000000005d20000,0x0000000005e20000)]
  0x00000000004eb800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5532, stack(0x00000000021a0000,0x00000000022a0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000005bf800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000005c20000,0x0000000005d20000] [id=7980]
  0x0000000005f87800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000006620000,0x0000000006720000] [id=7216]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000004e9920] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000005bf800
[0x00000000004e9e20] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x000000000a456000
[0x00000000004ea3a0] MethodData_lock - owner thread: 0x000000000a456000

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 349440K, used 2437K [0x00000000eaab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 349376K, 0% used [0x00000000eaab0000,0x00000000ead115a0,0x00000000fffe0000)
  from space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000ffff0000,0x00000000ffff0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64K, 0% used [0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000fffe0000,0x00000000ffff0000)
 PSOldGen        total 699072K, used 77778K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eaab0000, 0x00000000eaab0000)
  object space 699072K, 11% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c4bf4998,0x00000000eaab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83967K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c0000000)
  object space 83968K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bffffff0,0x00000000c0000000)

Code Cache  [0x00000000022a0000, 0x0000000002960000, 0x00000000052a0000)
 total_blobs=2085 nmethods=1504 adapters=533 free_code_cache=43378304 largest_free_block=12352

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077940000 - 0x0000000077ae9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077570000 - 0x000000007768f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefdf70000 - 0x000007fefdfdc000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feffb70000 - 0x000007feffc4b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe250000 - 0x000007fefe2ef000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe690000 - 0x000007fefe6af000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe810000 - 0x000007fefe93d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000000006d890000 - 0x000000006e048000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x0000000077470000 - 0x000000007756a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe3f0000 - 0x000007fefe457000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe940000 - 0x000007fefe94e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe170000 - 0x000007fefe239000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb770000 - 0x000007fefb7ab000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefe7e0000 - 0x000007fefe80e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefea70000 - 0x000007fefeb79000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006d800000 - 0x000000006d80e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d450000 - 0x000000006d477000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d850000 - 0x000000006d862000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd630000 - 0x000007fefd647000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefd330000 - 0x000007fefd377000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd090000 - 0x000007fefd0ae000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefdda0000 - 0x000007fefddaf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefdcd0000 - 0x000007fefdcdf000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000006d6a0000 - 0x000000006d6b7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefe790000 - 0x000007fefe7dd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe240000 - 0x000007fefe248000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefd5d0000 - 0x000007fefd625000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd5c0000 - 0x000007fefd5c7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefba50000 - 0x000007fefba65000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef9910000 - 0x000007fef9925000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef98f0000 - 0x000007fef9909000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefd450000 - 0x000007fefd4ab000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefa1f0000 - 0x000007fefa1fb000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef9fd0000 - 0x000007fef9fff000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x0000000077b10000 - 0x0000000077b17000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000007fefe9f0000 - 0x000007fefea61000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefcf60000 - 0x000007fefcf67000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb400000 - 0x000007fefb427000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefb3f0000 - 0x000007fefb3fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef8e10000 - 0x000007fef8e18000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefb2a0000 - 0x000007fefb2f3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006d5e0000 - 0x000000006d5ea000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000000006d6c0000 - 0x000000006d6cb000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\nio.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: E:\Programs\NXrepository\trunk\vat_wallet\target\surefire\surefirebooter3057161906587074677.jar E:\Programs\NXrepository\trunk\vat_wallet\target\surefire\surefire4775215429681292152tmp E:\Programs\NXrepository\trunk\vat_wallet\target\surefire\surefire6312715347409396828tmp
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Maven2/bin;G:\Matlab\runtime\win64;G:\Matlab\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin
USERNAME=Dimas
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 4192760k(689836k free), swap 8383672k(2200236k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.2-b06) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_27-b07), built on Jul 19 2011 01:08:22 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Mon Apr 02 12:08:50 2012
elapsed time: 1113 seconds
```

I have no idea what's going on. I can show any code but I don't know where to begin

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I just hit an issue where the null name of the 'God Mode' folder on my desktop was crashing my JVM. Deleting that file fixed my issue.

Comment: Wow, this was 7 years ago and I'm still getting this error in 2019 in Android Studio 3.5.x.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug inside JRE. You can do nothing about this, just send a bug report to the link provided:

> http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Try to use 32-bit version instead of 64. Try to use another JRE version (not 6.0_27-b07).

Comment: fixed using jdk 1.6_u31 for x86. Doesn't work for x64, don't know why. Also didn't find how to send bugreport

Answer (score 3):

Just dropping by to tell that I got the same error and it went away when I simply rebooted the computer. Try restarting the computer especially when everything was working fine earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to get this problem too, trying to re-installing the JVM (JDK+JRE) to newer version (7u4 to 7u5) but still getting the same error..

then I change the system classpath to point to the newer JDK 7u5(before was pointing to the directory of the older 7u4 which is not exist by now), and the problem is gone..

I don't know the reason but I got this one works on me.. (oh and yes, changing to 32-bit too)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using the connection string with `integratedSecurity=true` make sure that keep the connection string with credentials i.e. `DBusername` and `DBpassword`

*Note:*

1. This solution will works when the DB is not in localhost.
2. Make sure that the sqljdbc_auth.dll should be compatable with the hard ware

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me : 
I was using SQLJDBC Version 4.2 which was causing this error(This was working fine with Windows 7). Now I had upgraded to SQLJDBC Version 6.X and remapped the  sqljdbc_auth.dll for 64 bit version to my classpath (there are various ways to map it).

Config info: 
1) sqljdbc_6.0.8112.100_enu 
2) JDK Version 1.8.0_121 (Also tried with 1.8.0_161) 
3) OS-> 64 Bit Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred out of Apache code: org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal.  It's doing a java.io.DataInputStream.readInt.  I'm not familiar with what Apache may be doing at this point, but I suspect it's somehow been passed bad data (lots of opportunities for this in an unmarshal operation), perhaps from the other end of the conversation.

The thread involved is "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616", if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings of eclipse configuration setting file,which resides in Eclipse folder.
please do the following changes:
--XMS 40m
--XMS 768m

change the second --XMS value by reducing low.

Comment: Where did the mention eclipse, or out of memory? I don't think your answer is gonna help him. Especially if the problem is already solved by using a newer JDK.

Answer (score 0):

My project also is a maven project having AMQ. In my project there was a parent project with masterVersionNumber and all the sub projects were deriving their version number from it.

Example on the pom of sub project I had `<finalName>subProjectName${masterVersionNumber}</finalName>`    I got the above error.

So my work around was to remove `${masterVersionNumber}` and use `<finalName>subProjectName4.1.4</finalName>` and it worked perfectly fine during the build.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the same error when trying to open a JOptionPane or do anything with swing in IntelliJ. If anyone is getting this error mine was solved by shutting down Oracle SSO on my machine. I am on a work machine and pausing it did not solve the issue. I had to shut it down and then the error went away and everything worked. The same code works for me on Eclipse but not on IntelliJ. Weird. I shut it down by clicking on the carrot in the bottom right of my scren, right clicking the red oracle sso, and clicking shut down. IDK but my help desk said it was fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).