# <terminated> Filename [java application] C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

On running one of the codes without any compilation or runtime errors, the Eclipse for Java Developers' version in Windows 7 gives the message:

```
<terminated> Filename [java application] C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
```

I tried searching for it and found the Program Files folder could be a possible problem as it has space in its name.

I tried to fix it but am unable to change the path of the file when it runs i.e.: the runtime path of the application still remains as its mentioned in the title. Besides, I tried searching for why the message  should pop and am unable to get a relevant answer for my query.

I apologize if the question is trivial or repeated but since the available solutions didn't work for me, I'm posting the question.

Can anybody suggest a method to overcome the issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This message just means the program has finished running. Eclipse always outputs this when it runs a program and it finishes.

Comment: Hi Greg! Thanks for that but I must say that the code takes in a text file (.txt) and has to calculate certain parameters and output them. M not getting the output at all and the only message it displays is what is mentioned in the title.

Comment: probably you have not put the code properly - which was my case - wasted more than 1 hour doing this internet research to finally find the I missed syso. What an idiot I am.

Answer (score 0):

Some times  class with main() function is not saved so you will get this error,hence save all the classes.Still if it is not working just close Eclipse IDE and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem related to the JDK that you are using, try using the newer version of the JDK.

This happened with me while I was running a Spring Boot Application:
I was getting the same  message and there was no logs in the console, even the Spring Boot Startup logs were not present: (Attaching the image for reference)
[image]

Then, I opened the run configuration (Sprint Boot App- Run Configurations) and unchecked the ***Enable Life Cycle Management - Termination Timeout (ms)*** option as shown in the attached image:
[image]

Now I started getting another error: logs are given below:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=16392, tid=30144
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
```

I again searched for the solution of this problem and have got the solution given at [A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment. EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986227/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-exception-acces)
I just installed the latest version of JDK and have used that in my eclipse project and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I changed the work space and started from the beginning.
This seemed to fix the problem; everything is fine now.