# In my cucumber project, why is my test runner class getting terminated( without throwing any error) on executing it?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, test-runner

In my cucumber project, whenever I execute my testrunner (using junit), it terminates without throwing any error before any test is executed but when I execute my feature file then all the tests get executed without any issue, why, where am I going wrong?

Following is my project structure:

```
 src
    |____main
    |
    |____test
         |___java
             |___features
             |   |___quotation.feature
             |___stepdefinitions
             |   |___quotation.java
             |___AppHooks
             |   |___ApplicationHooks.java
             |___testRunners
                 |___MyTestRunner.java
```

[image]

Following is my testrunner class (MyTestRunner.java):

```
package testRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions( 
        features = "src/test/java/features/quotation.feature",
                  glue= {"stepdefinitions","AppHooks"},
                  plugin= {"pretty"}
        )
public class MyTestRunner {

}
```

[image]

Comment: It seem the feature path isn't been recognized. Try to use "features = "classpath:/features/quotation.feature", and check if your feature file follows the pattern starting with the keywork Feature:. Also I recomend you to change the .feature files to resources folder because "src" is Source folder not feature folder.

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Even moved the feature files folder to resource folder

Comment: Please check the following thread: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900401/terminated-filename-java-application-c-program-files-java-jre8-bin-javaw-ex)

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to solve the issue by selecting junit 4 as testrunner, earlier I was using junit 5. Junit 5 was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything I tried executing it through junit 4 and it worked, junit 5 was causing the issue. If anyone can throw light why it failed with junit 5 then that would be great..[image]

Comment: The runner you are using is for JUnit 4. To use JUnit 5 have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton